# error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ when using boost-bind to boost-function

Tags: c++, functor, boost-bind, boost-function

I am attempting to map the filter functor with one of the member methods of my class based on the value of an input string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

typedef boost::function < bool(std::map<std::string, std::string>, std::string) > MyFilterFunctor;

class MyClass
{
public:
    bool FilterFunction1(std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap, std::string filterValue)
    {
        //do something
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {

    MyFilterFunctor myFilter = boost::bind(&MyClass::FilterFunction1, _1, _2, _3);
    return 0;
}
```

And my error:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:375:
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator[]’ in ‘a[boost::_bi::storage3<A1, A2, boost::arg<I> >::a3_ [with A1 = boost::arg<1>, A2 = boost::arg<2>, int I = 3]]’
```

Edit:
I simplified my example slightly at the suggestion of a proposed answer to my question.
It has been suggested that I need to pass MyClass() as an argument to boost::bind, and this does solve the compilation error in the code segment posted.  However, it is not possible for me to do that given my code structure.  I would like to know why what I have done is different from this example in the boost::bind documentation:

```
struct X
{
    int f(int);
}

int main()
{ 
    boost::bind(&X::f, 1);     // error, X::f takes two arguments
    boost::bind(&X::f, _1, 1); // OK
}
```

Shouldn't the _1 parameter take care of the implicit 'this' which is being suggested I supply explicitly with MyClass()?

Comment: Yes, filterKey is a std::string.  I'll edit a variable declaration in to make it more clear.

Comment: A self-containing compilable minimal example that people can copy paste and try and play for themselves would maybe be helpful here.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Thank you for the suggestion, I've just done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `boost::assign::map_list_of` or `std::map`, the same error can be reproduced simply by this:

```
MyFilterFunctor mff;
auto bb = boost::bind(&MyClass::FilterFunction1, _1, _2, _3);
mff = bb;
```

`bb` requires 3 parameters: a `MyClass`, a `map<string,string>` and a `string`. `mff` requires 2 parameters, a `map<string,string>` and a `string`. The two are clearly incompatible.

Try `boost::bind(&MyClass::FilterFunction1, MyClass(), _1, _2))` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful response. It was my understanding that the first parameter, _1, would take the 'this' argument which is implicit in a call to a member function. That would avoid my having to pass an explicit call to the constructor for that class as one of the parameters, as my code is not structured in a way which would allow me to do that

Comment: @user1535568: Maybe if the type `MyFilterFunctor` also took a `MyClass&` argument?

Comment: @user1535568, where should the `this` object come from, if you don't want to call the constructor to create such an object? Perhaps your method should be static, so that it doesn't require a `this` pointer? If there is nothing from the object you need to pass along, then `static` should work fine.

Comment: @MvG Thanks, that actually just put what I was trying to do in perspective, and you are right.  The member function can be static, and I do not need a pointer to this.